# unable to compare value of a key in nested dictionary returned from ansble_devices fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, I am trying to compare string value of value of a key that is from ansible_devices variable and stuck at syntax error. I want to print msg only on `WHEN` condition Is met. basically, I want to only msg print when partitions are NULL or have no value in them.

I have below sample output and I am able to retrieve it but now I want to compare it with some string but failing
values.yml

```
null_partitions: "{}"
```

```
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }} {{ item }} {{ ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] }}"
  #when: "{{ ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] is defined }}"
  when: "ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] == ansible_devices[item] {{ null_partitions }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```

output error:

```
 fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] == ansible_devices[item] {{ null_partitions }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'. String: {% if ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] == ansible_devices[item] {} %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/run_ansible_playbook/k8s/baremetal/roles/local_volume_mount/tasks/main.yml': line 15, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# As per the warning in your output, 'when' clauses should not be wrapped with curly braces. Also better to use 'inventory_hostname' in this case\n- name: Print device partitions that are defined\n  ^ here\n"}
```

sample `ansible_Devices` is below

```
ok: [node1] => {
       "ansible_devices": {
           "loop0": {
               "holders": [],
               "host": "",
               "links": {
                   "ids": [],
                   "labels": [],
                   "masters": [],
                   "uuids": []
               },
               "model": null,
               "partitions": {},
               "removable": "0",
               "rotational": "1",
               "sas_address": null,
               "sas_device_handle": null,
               "scheduler_mode": "none",
               "sectors": "0",
               "sectorsize": "512",
               "size": "0.00 Bytes",
               "support_discard": "0",
               "vendor": null,
               "virtual": 1
           },
```

the output of my commented `when` is below

```
ok: [node] => (item=loop3) => {
      "msg": "node1 loop0 {}"
  }
```

As per comment, I tried

```
when: "ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] ==  null_partitions"
```

output was

```
  TASK [local_volume_mount : Print device partitions that are defined] 
skipping: [node] => (item=loop0)
```

not sure if my pattern `{}` is wrongly defined in values ? or if task is  literally looking for `null_partitions` as a string?

Comment: I think you need this: `when: "ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] == null_partitions"`

Comment: When you set `null_partitions`, get rid of the quotes around `{}`.

Comment: thanks: that fixed the error but somehow it skipped the task `skipping: [node] => (item=loop0)` so that means partitions value is not right that I set in `values.yml` ? 
also, am adding this to question

Comment: thans @Jack needed braces so we are good. am posting answer please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"partitions": {}` <= this in your result is **not** a string containing `"{}"` but an empty dictionary.

So the correct and secure way to write your `when` clause would be to check if the variable is a `mapping` and if is has a 0 length (i.e. has no declared keys).

```yaml
when:
  - ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] is mapping
  - ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] | length == 0
```

Regarding the `mapping` test, see https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#list-of-builtin-tests

Comment: appreciate it and it does work and I will adapt to this. However can you please explain what is `mapping` doing here? why can't i use just the `length == 0`. sorry new so clarifying.

Comment: You can drop that if you want. But lets imagine you could receive in your result `partitions: ""` (empty string), `partitions: []` (empty list) or even `partitions: null` (null value)  which all have a 0 length and that they would mean something different than an empty dict. Testing you get a mapping would make sure you only take an action on a very well known condition.

Answer (score 0):

With the partial help of comment from @jack, I was able to figure it out.

```
when: "ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] ==  {{ null_partitions }}"
```

the variable substitution needs to be braced.

output

```
ok: [node1] => (item=loop0) => {
14:36:45      "msg": "node1 loop0 {}"
14:36:45  }
```

Comment: Depending on your ansible version, this should at best fire a deprecation warning, at worse totally fail, because [you don't use double moustaches in a when clause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names). Removing them arround the identifier should fix the issue. Meanwhile, I suggest you look at my answer for a better way to make that test.

Comment: I did try removing the `{{ }}` but device was skipped or not sure how exactly you mean? I have posted in my question what I did. let know if am missing anything though I am gonna use your answer but this is for learning.

Comment: I will not dig into this because it is just a perfect illustration of why you should not directly compare to empty or boolean values. Ansible with it's jinja2 templating is tricky and you should avoid thinkgs like `a == true` (replace with `a | bool`), `b == ""` (replace with `b is string and b | length == 0` to be type safe) and more... There are a lot of good practice documents online you can browse. I also suggest having a look at [`ansible-lint`](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and its rules (going far beyond the current subject in terms of good practice).

Comment: sure. I posted another if you can have a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275344/search-a-string-in-ansible-when-condition-over-loop

Comment: You don't need quotes around the thing: `when: ansible_devices[item]['partitions'] == null_partitions`; then you don't need the braces.